# problem about drop-down menus with html+css

Tags: html, css

I am working on a top horizontal bar navigation which should be paired with a drop-down menu. This is my html&css code:

```css
ul {
   list-style-type: none;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   overflow:hidden;
   background-color: #333;
   position: sticky;
   top: 0;
   width: auto;
}

li {
   float: left;
   border-right: 1px solid #bbb;
}

li:last-child {
   border-right: none;
}

li a {
   display: block;
   color: white;
   text-align: center;
   padding:14px 16px;
   text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
   background-color: #111;
}

.active {
   background-color:#4CAF50
}

.right {
   float: right;
}

.subcontent {
  display: none;
  border: 1px solid #bbb;
}

.submenu:hover .subcontent {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
 <ul>
    <li><a href="Home.html">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="Search.html">FIND YOUR PLACE</a></li>
    <li><a href="AboutUs.html">ABOUT US</a></li>
    <li class="right"><a href="Login.html">Login</a></li>
    <li class="right submenu"><a href="Register.html" class="active">Register</a>
        <ul class="subcontent"> 
            <li><a href="RegisterCompany.html">Company</a></li>
            <li><a href="RegisterStudent.html" class="active">Student</a></li>
        </ul>
     </li>
</ul>
```

However, the black background also increases as the mouse hovers on the "Register". I have tried using position (relative and absolute) but it didn't work. Are there any other solutions to deal with it?

Comment: Your question isn't clear but I think you are having problem to show sub-menu on hover. in that case, remove `overflow: hidden` from `ul`. It will solve this problem. Another thing is that since you have used `float` property in `li`, you have to add clearfix hack into your `ul'. Otherwise, the height of the `ul` will be 0.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is probably something like this? Remove the `overflow: hidden;` from `ul` and in `li` replace `float: left;` with `display: inline-block;`

```css
ul {
   list-style-type: none;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   /*overflow: hidden;*/
   background-color: #333;
   position: sticky;
   top: 0;
   width: auto;
}

li {
   /*float: left;*/
   display: inline-block;
   border-right: 1px solid #bbb;
}

li:last-child {
   border-right: none;
}

li a {
   display: block;
   color: white;
   text-align: center;
   padding:14px 16px;
   text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
   background-color: #111;
}

.active {
   background-color:#4CAF50
}

.right {
   float: right;
}

.subcontent {
    display: none;
    border: 1px solid #bbb;
}

.submenu:hover .subcontent {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><a href="Home.html">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="Search.html">FIND YOUR PLACE</a></li>
    <li><a href="AboutUs.html">ABOUT US</a></li>
    <li class="right"><a href="Login.html">Login</a></li>
    <li class="right submenu"><a href="Register.html" class="active">Register</a>
        <ul class="subcontent"> 
            <li><a href="RegisterCompany.html">Company</a></li>
            <li><a href="RegisterStudent.html" class="active">Student</a></li>
        </ul>
     </li>
</ul>
```